# Why does XmlWriter throw an error in this code?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to write a chunk of XML data to a file like this:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D://project//data//" + i + ".xml"))
```

but it gives the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find a part of the path '`D:\project\data\1.xml`'.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`: Could not
>   find a part of the path '`D:\project\data\1.xml`'.

However, when I am reading an XML using an `XmlReader`:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("d://project//data.xml");
```

it creates the reader seamlessly and gives no error. I don't understand why.

EDIT: sorry both the folder paths are same and the correct one is d://project//data.xml

Comment: The folders are differents. Probably  d://project_elysian/  exists while D://project//data// doesn't.

Comment: The exception seems clears in your question: Directory does not exist,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spotted two things that are wrong here.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("d://project_elysian//data.xml");
```

and

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D://project//data//" + i + ".xml"))
```

The top `Create` uses a directory called `project_elysian` and the second is using `project`.

Also, you are creating a file called `data.xml` and the other you are using `data` as a directory.  If you are looking at incrementing the file, then you will need to remove the foward slash before the `i` variable

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D:/project/data" + i + ".xml"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Forward slashs don't need escaping. I'd try this instead

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\project\data\" + i + ".xml"))
```

You could also check the directory exists before trying to create the file with something like this

```
if(Directory.Exists(@"D:\project\data\"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You must create directory first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `D:\project\data\` doesn't exist while `d:\project_elysian\data.xml` exists.